# Spring Boot spring.config.additional-location as relative path

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, config

I have a Spring Boot project with this structure:

```
- /my-config
    - production-settings.yml
    - local-settings.yml
- /src
    - /main
        - /java
            - (the usual Java stuff)
        - /resources
            - application.yml
```

This is my `application.yml`:

```
my.personal.value: ${MY_PLACEHOLDER}
```

where I use a placeholder that is defined in `local-settings.yml`:

```
MY_PLACEHOLDER: something
```

Can somebody please tell me how to use the `spring.config.additional-location` with a relative path to the file `local-settings.yml`, so that the placeholder can be resolved.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `@PropertySource("file:./my-config/local-settings.yml")` to test the relative path to see if the `my.personal.value` is loaded.

```
@Configuration
// If the relative path is valid, just comment the PropertySource.
// @PropertySource("file:./my-config/local-settings.yml") 
public class MyPersonConfig {
    @Value("${my.personal.value}")
    private String value;

    @PostConstruct
    void run() {
        System.out.println(value);
    }
}
```

If it work fine you can set the JVM option and start your jar. Change the `local-settings.yml` or `production-settings.yml` for testing.

```
java -jar -Dspring.config.additional-location=file:./my-config/local-settings.yml build/libs/your.jar
```

The complete code is [here](https://github.com/changemyminds/stackoverflow/tree/master/68379728).

Comment: My point is that I don't know how to get to the relative path for my project, I've already tried every possible combination. BTW your solution doesn't work in my project.

Comment: You can use the `file:.` to get your project root directory. Can you explain why doesn't work ? have some exception ?

Comment: The file can't be found, I think because it's outside the classpath and it's not included in the JAR, or somethig like this.
Maybe the only solution is to move the `my-config` folder in the `resources` folder.

Comment: @Couper I update the complete code in the github. I use the relative path to read `my-config` folder you can see the sample. Hope it helps you.

Comment: For some reason in IntelliJ at first the relative path didn't work, but after some cleaning everything worked as expected. Thanks.